# Изменение рендера объекта vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пример: есть объект который приходит с сервера со значениями

```
histories {
    category: receive,
    status: ok,
    и тд
}
```

Отображаю в template:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="history in histories">
        <div>{{ history.category }}</div>
        <div>{{ history.status }}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

И не могу понять как лучше и правильнее произвести замену, то есть, например если приходит `category: receive` отобразить `User receive` (любой текст), а если `category: sent`, `Send by user`...
Полистал vue документацию и ответа не нашёл...

Проблему бы решил вычисляемыми свойствами vue, но объект перебирается в template и как поступить - не знаю...

Comment: Варианта как минимум три.

1. Функция которая пишет вам что хотите взависимости от того что вы передаете

2. используете v-if внутри вашего шаблона

3. Создаете еще один компонент и там выводите нужный вам текст опять же, используя v-if или функцию

Comment: Плохо понятно, но насколько понял Вам нужно использовать метод который принимает параметр history и возвращает исходя из значений history нужное Вам значение. В шаблоне сможете написать: {{ myMethod(history) }}